# Draw shape with inverted round corners "tunnel like style"

Tags: android, android-shapedrawable

[image: what I want to achieve]

How to draw the part I marked with the arrow? Beneath you see other parts I already drew. The surrounding space must be transparent.

Comment: see `android.graphics.Path` API

Comment: all you need is to call `Path#arcTo` twice

Comment: I'd prefer  a solution I can use with XML files in the drawable folder. If possible.

Comment: then try `VectorDrawable` but if you use it i'm afraid its going to have a fixed size

Comment: can you please elaborate the scenario where you need such type of requirement. May be I can help you.